# Why is the conversion from vertices to curve creating issues with the geometry?

Tags: edit-mode

I created a structure by converting the vertices to a curve.
However, the object looks like this:

How come there are issues with the geometry?

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create edge between two vertices (imported SVG)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314388/unable-to-create-edge-between-two-vertices-imported-svg) You do not say what your issues are, I guess unconnected corners? Curve control points cannot branch, they have only two connections maximum: one to the previous point, one to the next point. Exceptions are start and end point, they have only one connection.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't understand it. But nothing changes if I would make it a mesh first. I also tried doing it without the second layer, but I also don't understand why certain parts are smaller and others are bigger. I want the radius to be equal. When the curve is going 'around the corner' it is smaller.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200083 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259501 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353

Comment: Since you are user from 2023 and you asked already 10 Q ... you probably noticed you have a privilege to mark answer of your Q as "accepted" (solved) ... so please use this feature to keep this site organised https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even thickness is kept only for 2D curve (no way for 3D) ... there are some workarounds, but don't expect nice topology ...

If you connect curve in a good way ...

[image]

you can try Geometry Nodes ... *Resample Curve* to try eliminate un-even profile ...

[image]

[image]